# match values in 2 columns with the corresponding position in another character column

Tags: r, dplyr

An example dataframe:

```
example_df = data.frame(Gene.names = c("A", "B"),
                         Score = c("3.69,2.97,2.57,3.09,2.94",
                                   "3.99,2.27,2.89,2.89,2.00,2.52,2.09,2.83"),
                         ResidueAA = c("S", "Y"),
                         ResidueNo = c(3, 3),
                         Sequence = c("MSSYT", "MSSYTRAP") )
```

I want to check if the character at ResidueAA column at the position at ResidueNo column matches with the corresponding position in the ‘Sequence’ column. The output should be another column, say, ‘Check’ with a Yes or No.

This is working code:

```
example_df$Check=sapply(1:nrow(example_df),FUN=function(i){d=example_df[i,]; substr(d$Sequence,d$ResidueNo,d$ResidueNo)==d$ResidueAA})
```

Is there an easier/elegant way to do this? Ideally, I want something that works within a dplyr pipe.
Also, related to this, how can I extract the corresponding value from the 'Score' column into a new column, say, 'Score_1'?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `substr` directly

```
library(dplyr)
example_df  %>%
   mutate(Check = substr(Sequence, ResidueNo, ResidueNo) == ResidueAA)
```

-output

```
#  Gene.names                                   Score ResidueAA ResidueNo Sequence Check
#1          A                3.69,2.97,2.57,3.09,2.94         S         3    MSSYT  TRUE
#2          B 3.99,2.27,2.89,2.89,2.00,2.52,2.09,2.83         Y         3 MSSYTRAP FALSE
```

---

To create a new column with `match`ing 'Score', use `match` to get the corresponding index instead of `==` (which does an elementwise comparison) and use the index for extracting the 'Score' element

```
example_df  %>%
    mutate(Score2 =  Score[match(ResidueAA,
         substr(Sequence, ResidueNo, ResidueNo), ResidueAA)])
```

-output

```
#Gene.names                                   Score ResidueAA ResidueNo Sequence
#1          A                3.69,2.97,2.57,3.09,2.94         S         3    MSSYT
#2          B 3.99,2.27,2.89,2.89,2.00,2.52,2.09,2.83         Y         3 MSSYTRAP
#                    Score2
#1 3.69,2.97,2.57,3.09,2.94
#2                     <NA>
```

#### Update

Based on the comments, we need to extract the corresponding element of 'Score' based on the 'ResidueNo' `if` the `substr`ing values of 'Sequence' is the same as the 'ResidueAA'.  This can be done by splitting the 'Score' with `strsplit` into a `list`, extract the first element (`[[1]]` - after a `rowwise` operation) and then use the 'ResidueNo' to get the splitted word on that location

```
example_df  %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(Score2 = if(substr(Sequence, ResidueNo, ResidueNo) == 
    ResidueAA) strsplit(Score, ",")[[1]][ResidueNo] else NA_character_) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  Gene.names Score                                   ResidueAA ResidueNo Sequence Score2
#  <chr>      <chr>                                   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>    <chr> 
#1 A          3.69,2.97,2.57,3.09,2.94                S                 3 MSSYT    2.57  
#2 B          3.99,2.27,2.89,2.89,2.00,2.52,2.09,2.83 Y                 3 MSSYTRAP <NA>
```

---

Or another option is `separate_rows` to split the rows to expand the data, then do a group by 'Gene.names', `summarise to get the corresponding 'Score2' element (similar to previous solution) and do a join with the original dataset

```
library(tidyr)
example_df %>%
    separate_rows(Score, sep= ",") %>% 
    group_by(Gene.names) %>% 
    summarise(Score2 = if(substr(first(Sequence), first(ResidueNo), first(ResidueNo)) ==
       first(ResidueAA)) Score[first(ResidueNo)] else
         NA_character_, .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    right_join(example_df)
```

Comment: How can I extract the corresponding value from the 'Score' column into a new column, say, 'Score_1'?

Comment: @ip2018 May be you need `match` i.e. `example_df  %>%
      mutate(Score2 =  Score[match(substr(Sequence, ResidueNo, ResidueNo), ResidueAA)])`

Comment: Not working. Its the same value in each row

Comment: @ip2018 Do you expect `NA` for the second case

Comment: @ip2018 The Sequence element extracted is 'S' in both cases as 'ResidueNo' is 3 for both and it doesn't have a match with 'Y' for second row

Comment: Yes, I expect 'NA' if there is no match. In reality, I have removed all such instances where there is no match @akrun

Comment: @ip2018 Please check my updated code.  It returns NA

Comment: Nope same thing. Also, I am getting all values of the rows and not just the one I want

Comment: @ip2018 Please check the output I showed in the post.  It is returning NA.  I changed the order in `match`

Comment: Not sure whats wrong but not working for me. Also, the only values I want in 'Score2` is 2.57 (for A) and NA (for B) and not all of them.

Comment: @ip2018 May be the logic you mentioned is not clear.  The 'Score' is a string column.  So, it is extracting the element as a whole

Comment: yes, sorry my bad, that makes sense. The Score column indeed is a string column. Any way I can extract the specific value?

Comment: yes, I will give it to you for your help and the hard work. Unfortunately, cant give both of the nice answers

Answer (score 1):

To get an individual score, you would need to split the string and return the index corresponding to the position. You could vectorize this, e.g.:

```r
getScore <- Vectorize(function(x, pos) unlist(strsplit(x, ",", TRUE), use.names = FALSE)[pos])
example_df %>% mutate(check=substr(Sequence, ResidueNo, ResidueNo) == ResidueAA, 
                      MyScore=ifelse(check, as.numeric(getScore(Score, ResidueNo)), NA))
#>   Gene.names                                   Score ResidueAA ResidueNo
#> 1          A                3.69,2.97,2.57,3.09,2.94         S         3
#> 2          B 3.99,2.27,2.89,2.89,2.00,2.52,2.09,2.83         Y         3
#>   Sequence check MyScore
#> 1    MSSYT  TRUE    2.57
#> 2 MSSYTRAP FALSE      NA
```